# Polynomial Greatest Common Divisor C++

Tags: c++, polynomial-math, greatest-common-divisor, polynomials

Here is my attempt to implement a program that finds GCD of two polynomials.
I realize there is a problem in division method. A while loop decrementing the degree of a resulting polynomial in `division()` goes into "infinity" in some cases, and I can't understand in which exactly.

*Any clues on what goes wrong here?*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>



using namespace std;

//polynomial------------------------------
struct polynomial {
    float *coeff;
    int degree;
};

/*function declaration */
int get_data(polynomial *P); 
int display(polynomial *P);
int division(polynomial *P, polynomial *Q, polynomial *H, polynomial *R);
int polcpy(polynomial *p, polynomial *q);
void GCDPol(polynomial *P,polynomial *Q, polynomial *R);

//GCD of two polynomials------------------
void GCDpol(polynomial *P,polynomial *Q, polynomial *R) {
    polynomial *res, *v;
    res = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));  
    v = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));  
    while(1) {
        division(P, Q, v, R);
        if(R->degree==0 && R->coeff[0]==0)
            break;
        else
            polcpy(P,Q);
            polcpy(Q,R);
    }
    polcpy(R,Q);
    free(res);
    free(v);
}

//pol copy--------------------------------
int polcpy(polynomial *p, polynomial *q) {
    p->degree=q->degree;
    p->coeff = new float[p->degree + 1];
    for (int i=0; i<=p->degree; i++) 
        p->coeff[i]=q->coeff[i];
    return 0;
}

//division--------------------------------
int division(polynomial *P, polynomial *Q, polynomial *H, polynomial *R) {
    float u;
    int x;
    polynomial *nh, *nr;
    nh = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));
    nr = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));

    /*Euclidian Long Division*/
    polcpy(nr, P);  
    nh->degree = P->degree - Q->degree;
    nh->coeff = new float[nh->degree + 1];
    for (int i=nh->degree; i>=0; i--)  {
        nh->coeff[i] = nr->coeff[nr->degree] / Q->coeff[Q->degree];
        for (int j=i; j <= nr->degree; j++) {
            u = nh->coeff[i] * Q->coeff[j-i];
            nr->coeff[j] = nr->coeff[j] - u;
        }
        if (nr->degree > 0)  
            nr->degree--;
    }

    /*Quotient*/
    polcpy(H, nh);  
    /*Remainder*/   
    polcpy(R, nr);
    while(R->coeff[R->degree] == 0) {
        R->degree--;
    }   
    free(nh); 
    free(nr);
    return 0;
}

//display-------------------------------
int display(polynomial *P) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = P->degree; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << P->coeff[i] << "x^" << i;
        if ((i - 1) != -1)
            cout << "+";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//get_data------------------------------
int get_data(polynomial *P) {
    cout << "Enter Degree Of Polynomial:";
    cin >> P->degree;
    P->coeff = new float[P->degree + 1];
    for (int i = P->degree; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << "Enter coefficient of x^" << i << ":";
        cin >> P->coeff[i];
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    polynomial *P, *Q, *R, *H;
    P = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));
    Q = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));
    R = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));
    H = (polynomial *) calloc(1,sizeof(polynomial));
    cout<<"GDC\n";
    get_data(P);
    get_data(Q);
    cout << "Polynomial1:";
    display(P);
    cout << "Polynomial2:";
    display(Q);
    GCDpol(P,Q,R);
    display(R);
    free(R);
    free(P);
    free(Q);
    free(H);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you stated precisely what's going wrong (and where if you know), rather than give a vague description. Also, sample inputs that it goes wrong with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that the line

```
if(R->degree==0 && R->coeff[0]==0)
        break;
```

is what's broken. Your coefficients are floats. Because computers are (unfortunately) finite, there will be small errors in your float computation. The code only exits the while loop if the coefficient is exactly 0. It seems likely that on some inputs, although it should divide evenly, you get `R->coeff[0] = 0.0000000001` or some other very small value that is not exactly 0.

Try checking if the absolute value is within some very small tolerance (something like 10^-10 or 10^-12.) If you actually want the exact value, you'll need to look into exact precision floats, which is its own can of worms.

(Looking at the code more closely, you do exact equality checks in other places too - these should all be changed to checking the absolute value is very small.)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(R->coeff[R->degree] == 0) {
    R->degree--;
}
```

This goes badly wrong if `R` is the zero polynomial.

Comment: Aside: doing exact comparisons with `float` data is usually a bad idea, although _maybe_ it's okay here, or even the right thing to do. But consider treating sufficiently small coefficients as zero.

Answer (score 1):

This C++ library implements polynomial division: [PolynomialDivHang_test_no_hang](https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/77d79f62ded371579ed2812850b81a9f30d2693e/omnn/math/test/Sum_test.cpp#L308)